# PHPSpec: how to call factory method multiple times on single test

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, phpspec

I trying to get my hands dirty with PHPSpec.

Basically Im trying to make a TimeSpan as a practice.
I want to make sure that all possible valid inputs are accepted.

```
function it_can_be_created_from_24_format()
    {
        $hours = 24;
        $minutes = 60;
        $seconds = 60;
        for ($h = 1; $h < $hours; $h++) {
            for ($m = 1; $m < $minutes; $m++) {
                for ($s = 1; $s < $seconds; $s++) {
                    $this->beConstructedThrough('fromString', [$this->buildTimeString($h, $m, $s)]);
                    $this->shouldNotThrow(\InvalidArgumentException::class)->duringInstantiation();
                    $this->getHours()->shouldBe($h);
                    $this->getMinutes()->shouldBe($m);
                    $this->getSeconds()->shouldBe($s);
                }
            }
        }
    }


private function buildTimeString($h, $m, $s)
    {
        $minutes = ($m < 9) ? '0'.$m : $m;
        $seconds = ($s < 9) ? '0'.$s : $s;
        return sprintf('%s:%s:%s', $h, $minutes, $seconds);
    }
```

But im receiving this error: 
`you can not change object construction method when it is already instantiated`
[image]

Comment: You should try to provide errors as text in your question unless there's no other way for you to display them.

Comment: Oops yeah youre right so it will be searcheable. Thanks

Comment: Try writing one spec at a time. Have the examples be meaningful variations, rather than trying to validate all inputs. The goal of SpecBDD tools like phpspec is to be human readable.
The issue you are seeing is due to trying to instantiate more than one of the subject-under-test within a single example.

Comment: I guess you're right, I'll try to breakdown it to test for possible outcomes when constructing the object and see if its doing the correct behavior based on the input.